# can't use SendMessage_EX twice in my c# program

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I am facing a very strange problem and couldn't figure out where's the mistake. I'm using SendMessage_EX to get a specified line's text:

```cs
SendMessage_Ex(hr.Handle, EM_GETLINE, l, buffer);
```

then I call the method twice like this:

```cs
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
SendMessage_Ex(hr.Handle, EM_GETLINE, 5, buffer);
StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder(256);
SendMessage_Ex(hr.Handle, EM_GETLINE, 4, buffer1);
```

It gets text of line 5 correctly but then for line 4, It returns nothing(buffer1 is empty).
If I reverse it and first get line 4 and then line 5, It returns the text of line 4 and nothing for line 5.

It's very strange and I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake, but where is the mistake?
I appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Obviously you forgot to include body of SendMessage_Ex() method so we can take a look how it read a buffer

Comment: I was able to reproduce it.  The prototype for the windows API call is:          [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        private static extern int SendMessage_Ex
         (IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
        private const int EM_GETLINE = 0xc4;

Comment: Thanks for replies, I had already used the exact dllimport and declared EM_GETLINE (I thought it was clear, so I didn’t mention the code in question,sorry) But I don't know why I cannot call it consequently. :( Any ideas?

Comment: @sllev SendMessage_EX() is not my method, it's from user32.dll as steve mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EM_GETLINE message wants the size of the buffer passed in the same parameter it uses for a buffer.  I couldn't just set the 0 index of the StringBuilder without initializing it to some value (got an index exception).

This seems to work:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("   ", 256);
buffer[0] = (char)256;   
int Result = SendMessage_Ex(textBox1.Handle, EM_GETLINE, 3, buffer);

StringBuilder buffer1 = new StringBuilder("   ", 256);
buffer1[0] = (char)256;
int Result1 = SendMessage_Ex(textBox1.Handle, EM_GETLINE, 2, buffer1);

MessageBox.Show(buffer.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(buffer1.ToString());
```