# EM_GETLINE does not return anything in second calling

Tags: c#, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can't use SendMessage_EX twice in my c# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050755/cant-use-sendmessage-ex-twice-in-my-c-sharp-program)

I use EM_GETLINE message, to get the text in specific row, but when I call it the second time it returns an empty string.

Run this code, and click on button1 twice, in the first click the text will show in the message box, but in the second time, will show message box empty.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(256);
        SendMessage_Ex(richTextBox1.Handle, EM_GETLINE, 0, str);
        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
    }
    public const int EM_GETLINE = 0xc4;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
    public static extern int SendMessage_Ex(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
```

Comment: It is a miracle it returns anything on the first call.  The buffer must be initialized with a word that states the buffer length.  You can't do that with StringBuilder.  Use the RichTextBox.Lines property instead.  Or SelectedText if you want to burn less cpu.

Comment: So how this message should work?